# Python map v2.7 no long working in v3.2

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, python-3.x

My code in Python v2.7 is no longer working in Python v3.2

I have searched everywhere but I do not find this case. It seems that the function `self.buildGraph(i, n)` is never actually called

```
n = 33
map(lambda i : self.buildGraph(i, n), range(n))
```

however with the function:

```
map(lambda x : fu(a, x), range(10))
```

there is no problem.

Comment: There is no actual difference between these two examples. Hence if it really is the case for you that one works and the other doesn't, then the problem is not in the map statements. You need to include a full but minimal example of what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

In python 3 [map](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#map) returns [lazy iterator object](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), like [imap](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) in python 2, so you need to evaluate your iterator, for example:

```
list(map(lambda i : self.buildGraph(i, n), range(n)))
```

Comment: Found the issue, when I wanted to test the second map function, I executed `print(list(the_map...))`

Anyway, I replaced the code now with:

    [self.buildGraph(i, n) for i in range(n)]

And this performs remarkably well.

Comment: @user1668303 Please don't use list comprehensions, or `map`, like that. Use an explicit for loop for mutations like this. Only use the former for generating data without side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how one of your `map` examples gives what you expect, while the other one doesn't, but as a general tip, when using existing 2.x code in 3.x - use the [2to3 tool](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) to make sure that the changes in behavior between map/filter/range etc... don't bite you in the rear.